# Trying to understand extends syntax in Scala

Tags: scala

I recently saw the following piece of code and I'm trying to understand the syntax.

What I don't understand is `object Widget extends ((Int, String, DateTime) => Widget )` part. Can someone explain the syntax and what's happening here?

```
case class Widget(
  id      : Int,
  name    : String,
  created : DateTime = now
)

object Widget extends ((
  Int,
  String,
  DateTime
) => Widget) { ..... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is your object is extending a `Function` type which takes as input the triplet of types `Int`, `String`, and `DateTime` and returns a `Widget`.  Hence, you will need to override the `apply(Int, String, DateTime)` function.  Once you've done that, you will have made a function named `Widget`.  This in fact is what a `case class` implements for you behind the scenes.  In this case, I *believe* your `Widget` object's definition of the function will take precedence over the default `case class` one.